# How to use ksoap timeout in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, ksoap2

I would like to make make userregistartion app in Blackberry. In which I have used ksoap2 to send request to server and get response from server.

I want that when I send request to server and within 10 second if server not give any response than say any msg like "Try again". and before 10sec server give response then proceed further.

How's this possible? Is there used TimerTask or any method for Tomeout in Ksoap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be the following example will helpful for you:

```
String ht_params = ";ConnectionTimeout=10000"; // 10 seconds timeout
HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(this.SERVICE_URL + ht_params);
```

I'm from Russia, so my English is very bad.